# How can I install libtoolize in cygwin?

Tags: windows, cygwin, libtool

When I'm trying to build Apache Thrift source in cygwin, I'm getting error saying "Couldn't find libtoolize!". How can I install libtoolize in cygwin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'libtoolize' is a part of libtool. You can dowload latest version of libtool from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libtool/, extract it, then run ./configure and make install from cygwin terminal.

Comment: You will also need GNU M4 1.4.6 or later to install libtool-2.4.6 and above. So make sure in your Cygwin installer that you select the "m4" package from the "Interpreters" section.

Answer (score 13):

You will need **GNU M4** 1.4.6 or later to install **LibTool** (which includes `libtoolize`).

Good news is that you can easily do it if you run the Cygwin installer (no worries, it will keep your Cygwin installation and add new packages if you select them). So all you need to do is to click on the following buttons:

**GNU M4 installation**

[image]

**LibTool installation**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
python -mpip get-install libtoolize
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From Review.